# How to auto position my buttons on my website with different screen resolution?

Tags: css

I am working on my website and new to it. I have lots of buttons in my website but there position changes when the screen resolution is minimized. I have also provided my CSS code. Please help me what to do to make my buttons positioned automatically with different screen resolution.

```css
/* Set a style for the submit/send button */
.form-container .btn{
  background-color: #009900;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.form-container .send{
 margin-top: 38.5%;
 margin-right:-17.5%;
 padding: 5px 52px;
}
/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 6.5px;
  width: 48%;
}
```

[Click here to see the snapshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzrfI.png)

Comment: please share full code. not only css. share also html code and other css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `position:relative` for parent div. after, use `position:absolute` and `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` values for children. `position:relative` positioning according to itself.

try this

```
/* Set a style for the submit/send button */

.form-container {
  position:relative;
}

.form-container .btn{
  background-color: #009900;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.form-container .send{
   position:absolute;
   top: 38.5%;
   right:-17.5%;
   padding: 5px 52px;
}
/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position:absolute;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: 6.5px;
  width: 48%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things that could be fixed.

First, you should use `position:absolute` for children elements of `.formContainer`. This helps in calculating position of the children(button in your case) based on the parent.

Secondly, using -ve margin creates more problems than it solves. Its better to use `top`, `left`, etc to position your elements.

```
.cancel{
position:absolute,
right: -10px,
width: 5%
}
```

This would ensure that the btn does not go beyond your form container and always renders 10 pixels to the right border of the container.

Comment: Hi, ya i had tried position:absolute for children elements of .formContainer and that worked. Thank you!!

Comment: Good. Usually programmers try out css properties by inspecting the element in chrome/mozilla and modifying the properties in the console.